# Is it possible to be a refresh control unhidden if tableview is hidden?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a tableview with refresh control:

```
tableView.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
tableView.refreshControl?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refresh), for: .valueChanged)
```

And I have a custom SkeletonView which replaced by tableview when user pull to refresh:

```
private func setLoading(_ loading: Bool) {
        if loading {
            tableView.isHidden = true
            tableView.scrollToTop(animated: false)
            setSkeletonView(isHidden: false)
        } else {
            setSkeletonView(isHidden: true)
            tableView.isHidden = false
        }
 }
```

When I am pulling my refresh control it disseapears with a tableview and appears after successful loading. Also, I don't want to set a largeTitle navbar, I want to use a small one.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to be a refresh control unhidden if tableview is hidden?

Basically no. If B is a subview of A then if A is hidden, B is hidden.